# Возможна ли полноценная реализация COMET при условии использования php в серверной части?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

Спрашиваю потому, что в проекте (Angular JS + Laravel) нужно реализовать чат - очень хотелось бы использовать socket.io, но, насколько я знаю, без node.js не обойтись, а хотелось бы без нее. Избегаю ноды потому, что наработался с ней и очень боюсь ее падений. Посоветуйте что-нибудь для этой связки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы точно хотите использовать именно модель COMET?

Просто **COMET'ом** - обычно называют модель Web-приложения, в которой запрос отправляется на сервер и сохраняется в нем в течение длительного времени, пока не сработает таймер или не произойдет событие на сервере. Изначально термин "Comet" (введен в 2006 году Алексом Расселом) ссылался на HTTP Streaming и HTTP Polling.

Модель Comet в 2016 году утратила свою позицию. Сейчас написание сложного кода на клиентской и серверной стороне, передаче лишних данных выглядит как велосипед. Во всех браузерах поддерживается Websockets и он является стандартизированным. Среди его плюсов: минимальные задержки, снижение количества используемого трафика и двусторонние соединения.

Реализовать чат на Websockets будет очень просто и удобно. Для реализации сервера на PHP, я Вам предлагаю [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman), очень удобная библиотека для реализации различных протоколов и удобным мониторингом клиентов. Хотя по сути, Вам подойдет абсолютно любой сервер, достаточно на github набрать в поиске websockets и выбрать язык PHP.

Если же вы будете реализовать Сomet, то никакой библиотеки не нужно, достаточно ведь Вам по сути иметь скрипт, который работая в постоянном цикле будет завершаться по определенному времени или выдавать событие по его наступлению (реализация Long Polling)